# how to end reciving data

Tags: c++, sockets, http, recv

### How to end reciving data from client ?

I Wrote this code that listen on port 80

I want to get request from client browser and send response

#### C++ :

```
    while ( (l = recv(client, buff, 250, 0)) > 0){
        buff[l] = '\0';
        printf(buff);
    }
    sprintf_s(buff,"<h1>Hello World</h1>");
    send(client, buff, strlen(buff), 0);
    closesocket(client);
```

this while never end... and after the client's browser send request to the server my code stop on **recv()** function..... it means recv() function never return zero....
What should i do to know that receving data has finished ?

Answer (score 0):

You work with network requests in a wrong way.

`recv` function in blocking mode returns zero when a connection has been closed. It means that you cannot send data after `recv` returned zero.

In you case you should parse the received data and wait for end-of-request marker (empty line).

Comment: how to know recving data is finished??

Comment: i don't want use Content-length